# Prove by contradiction: Let n > 1. Let a be the smallest factor of n that is greater than 1. Prove a is prime.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Here is what I have in my proof so far.

Proof.
Let $n$ be any integer greater than 1. Let $a$ be the smallest factor of $n$ that is greater than 1.
Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $a$ is not prime.
Then $n = ak$ for some integer $k$, and $a$ is composite, that is, there is an integer $c$ such that $1 < c < a$ and $c|a$.

I am stuck here. I think I made the right move by discussing that since $a > 1$ and $a$ is not prime, it's composite. How can I link that with my divisibility definition, $n = ak$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need $n=ak$. You need to use that $c|a|n$. If $c$ divides $a$ and is not $1$, this is a contradiction to the fact that $a$ is the smallest factor.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n$={$x \in \Bbb N \;|\; x>1, x|n$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$}

Then this set $S_n$ must have a smallest element by the well-ordering principle, call it $a \in S_n$

Now suppose that this smallest element is a composite.  Then there exists $b$ such that $b | a$

But since $n=am$ for some $m \in \Bbb N$ and $b|a$, then $n=bjm$ for some $j \in \Bbb N$.  Hence $b|n$

However, then $b \in S_n$ and $b < a$, contradicting that $a$ is our smallest element of $S_n$.

So we can conlude that $a$ must be prime.